# AWS S3 vs EFS - how does mounting make the difference between them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-efs

I guess I don't really understand the meaning of "remote mounting" so I can't understand how these two technologies differ from each other. I know that using AWS EFS for reading and writing is faster than using s3, but why? what is the difference between the two methods/technologies? How does mounting affect it? If not by mounting to S3, how do we communicate with it?

A lot of questions :)

Comment: Amazon EFS acts like a network file system. It is a virtual disk. Amazon S3 is an object storage system that is not intended to be "mounted". It is accessed via API calls.

Comment: And why one is faster than the other?

Answer (score 0):

In short:

S3 is object storage

EFS is file sharing service like NFS